# Find a string in netsuite, and print it

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

In netsuite suitescript 1.0, I want to check whether a string has a set of keywords. In javascript there is function called as .includes("Set_of_keywords_to_be_searched");
I tried .includes in netsuite but its giving error.

Eg:

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the javascript.";
var n = str.includes("world");     // this will return true
var n = str.includes("Apple");     // this will return false
```

I want similar function in netsuite.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `RegExp` and the `test` method. See [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Will look something like

```js
var pattern = /world/;
var n = pattern.test(str);
```

`String#includes` was only added in ES2015. NetSuite is running the Rhino 1.7 JS engine, which does not support any ES2015 or later features of JS.

Comment: you provide far better solutions then netsuite gold support.
both the things you mentioned worked.
Thanks

Comment: I am very curious what they told you to do instead.

Comment: They told: This is not part of Netsuite support since the solution you want is related to javascript. 
I told them that I am just giving you the example of what I want but they told there is no solution to such problem.

Answer (score 7):

I usually go for the search method, its easy to use and readable. If the word is found this method returns the index of the first occurrence and it will return -1 if it can't find the word(s).

```
var hasWorld = str.search("world") !=-1;
```